# Spring Boot: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So im using Thymeleaf with Spring Boot to create a web application and so far its going great.  Recently I noticed that an error will be caused whenever I refresh a certain page after a little while. I know this question was asked multiple times but there is literally no answer that I found to fix my problem and I dont see one that relates to the specifications of mine.

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewSub", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewPost(ModelAndView modelAndView, Sub sub, Comment comment, Post post) {
    modelAndView.addObject("sub", sub);
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:viewSub/" + sub.getId());

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/viewSub/{subId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPost(@PathVariable Long subId, Sub sub, Comment comment, Post post) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("post", new Post());
    mav.addObject("comment", new Comment());
    mav.addObject("sub", subRepository.findById(subId).get());
    mav.setViewName("viewSub");
    return mav;
}
```

Thymeleaf portion(Causing the problem):

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createNewPost}" th:object="${comment}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="header">Header</label></td>
                <td><input th:object="${post}" th:field="*{header}" type="text" name="header"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="body">Body</label></td>
                <td><input th:field="*{body}" type="text" name="body"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" th:object="${sub}" name="id" th:value="${sub.id}"/>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Clear"/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Error:

````
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/viewSub.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template: "viewSub" - line 220, col 19)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template: "viewSub" - line 220, col 19)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2999) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.saveTokenIfNecessary(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:175) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.getToken(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.getExtraHiddenFields(CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.java:71) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestDataValueProcessor.getExtraHiddenFields(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestDataValueProcessor.java:80) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.requestdata.RequestDataValueProcessorUtils.getExtraHiddenFields(RequestDataValueProcessorUtils.java:79) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor.doProcess(SpringActionTagProcessor.java:118) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:160) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 99 common frames omitted```
````

Comment: I'm working on a Thymeleaf/Spring project myself. While I haven't encountered something similair, I do know that Thymeleaf throws such exceptions when it doesn't receive what it needs. So I'm thinking: does your post-method for that form return to the same page? Or have you implemented a redirect to another page?

Comment: I did think about that, I checked my methods before and I was pretty sure I was handing it everything.  Ill check again.  And no it doesnt redirect to another page as in the model and view set name is the thymeleaf template ("viewPost") and not ex.("redirect:viewPost/25")

Comment: and what if you used the different way of Thymeleaf notations? 
 @GetMapping("/viewSub/{subId}")
    public String getPost(@PathVariable Long subId, Sub sub, Comment comment, Post post, Model mav) {
        mav.addAttribute("post", new Post());
        mav.addAttribute("comment", new Comment());
        mav.addAttribute("sub", subRepository.findById(subId).get());
        return "viewSub";
    }
where the return String is your template's [path from recource folder + templatename]. I'm grasping at straws here without a debugger.

Comment: Sadly that doesnt fix it, I feel like im bound to come to a fix during my work on this project.  I should really learn how to use the debugger haha.

Comment: Last week, I encountered the same exception. It was caused by something I changed in my html-template. Suddenly Thymeleaf didn't know how to parse a certain object because it wasn't provided through all the paths leading to the template. The problem with those exceptions, is that they never point directly to the problem. If I were you, I'd try to go through your changelogs and try to determine what you changed and what the impact could be. In my case, I called an intValue() on a Double that wasn't always provided. A th:if="${object.field != null}" was a quickfix

Comment: Judging from the trace you provided, if it's a parser error due to having a form and csrf, you may check this answer: https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/67192363/4598590